# Why can you assign non-optional values to optional types in Swift?

Tags: swift

Why do assignments involving Swift optionals type check?
For example in,

```
 var foo : Int? = 0
 foo = foo!
```

foo and foo! do not have the same type. Shouldn't you need to wrap the unwrapped value to assign it to an optional type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of the syntactic sugar behind optionals. Assigning a non-optional value is *how* you wrap it in the optional type.

Since an optional indicates the presence or absence of a value, you shouldn't have to do anything special to indicate the presence of a value other than provide one. For example, in a function:

```
func gimmeSomethingMaybe() -> String? {
    if arc4random_uniform(10) > 7 {
        return "something"
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Imagine if every time you wanted to return a real value from a function that's capable of returning nil, you had to write `return Optional(value)`. That'd get old pretty fast, right? Optionals are an important feature of the language — even though they're actually implemented by the standard library, the syntactic sugar / automatic wrapping is there to keep it from being tedious to use them.

---

Edit: just to go a bit further into this... the sugar also helps to enforce the notion that a real value should not be optional. For example:

```
let one = 1
one? // error (in Swift 1.2, allowed but meaningless in Swift 1.1)
"two"? // error (ditto)
```

You can create an optional wrapping a real value with the `Optional(one)` initializer, but that has little semantic meaning on its own, so you almost never need to.

Optionals should come into play when there's "mystery" as to whether a value is present or absent — that is, when whether one part of a program receives a value (or no value) depends on state unknown to that part of the program. If you know you have a real value, there's no mystery... instead, you let the unknown come into play at the boundary between the code that knows the value and the code that doesn't know — that is, the function/method/property definition that hands that value off to somewhere.

Comment: My question correctly got marked as duplicate. I understand everything except for one part. Can you respond to the last paragraph of my question from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291433/why-can-you-assign-an-non-optional-to-an-optional-without-any-error)

Answer (score 0):

After reading rickster's answer, I came up with a simple laymen terms answer. To me the whole whole gist of his answer is

> Since an optional indicates the presence or absence of a value, you
>   shouldn't have to do anything special to indicate the presence of a
>   value other than provide one

An optional is an enum. Which has 2 cases a or b.

```
                                      String?
                                         |
                                An enum with 2 cases
                                         |                               
                                 a               b
                                 |               |
                                Set            notSet
                                 |               |
                        any value like "hi"     nil
```

So you could do either of the things when you want to assign to an optional.

Say the value is either:

- a: it's set to "hi"
- b: it's not set, so it's `nil`
- c: it just equals to another enum ie another optional

code:

```
var str : String?
var anotherOptional : String?

str = nil // nil <-- this is like case b
str = "hi" // "hi" <-- this is like case a

str = anotherOptional // nil <-- this is like case c

anotherOptional = "hi again"
str = anotherOptional // "hi again" <-- this is like case c
```